# Copy model instances in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `Foo` with attributes `id, name, location`.
I have an instance of `Foo`:

```
f1 = Foo.new
f1.name = "Bar"
f1.location = "Foo York"
f1.save
```

I would like to copy `f1` and from that copy, create another instance of the `Foo` model, but I don't want `f1.id` to carry over to `f2.id` (I don't want to explicitly assign that, I want the db to handle it, as it should).

Is there a simple way to do this, other than manually copying each attribute? Any built in functions or would writing one be the best route?

Thanks

Comment: Thus far I have created a method .copy for the specific model, ie:
f2 = f1.copy
f2.name = "Baz"
f2.save
still trying different solutions

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is what [ActiveRecord::Base#clone](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/clone) method is for:

```
@bar = @foo.clone

@bar.save
```

Comment: Use @foo.dup now for rails 3.1 and on. Clone copies the id.

Comment: Note that both `@foo.dup` and `@foo.clone` only perform shallow copies, and will still contain reference to other objects when copying into more complex variables.

Comment: Nowadays, this is the wrong answer. `clone` uses the same attributes as the original. If the attributes of the clone are changed, the original changes as well. Use `dup` instead.

Answer (score 81):

As per the following question, if you are using Rails >= 3.1, you can use `object.dup` :

[What is the easiest way to duplicate an activerecord record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record)

Answer (score 3):

You can make duplicate record in rails like

```
@bar = @foo.dup
@bar.save!
```

Answer (score 2):

a **wrong** way to do this would be:

```
f2 = Foo.new( f1.attributes )     # wrong!
f2.save                           # wrong!
```

or in one line, but still **wrong**:

```
f2 = Foo.create( f1.attributes )  # wrong!
```

see comments for details

Comment: THIS WILL NOT WORK!
all attributes that are not in attr_accessible, or are in attr_protected will be lost! or if you are using one of the attribute protection plugins will result in an exception thrown!

Comment: Not only that, all the ids are still the same, so save will just do an update

Answer (score -2):

You could use the built-in `attributes` methods that rails provides. E.g.

```
f2 = Foo.new(f1.attributes)
```

or

```
f2 = Foo.new
f2.attributes = f1.attributes
```

Comment: This is not the right way. The Primary Key of `f1` will get copied over to `f2`.

Comment: No, it won't. The primary key is not included in attributes assigned in this way in a similar way to any attr_protected attributes.

Comment: For me in Rails 3.1, it seems clone does copy the id across. But dup does not.