# Copy model instances in Rails with single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, copy, clone, sti, dup

I have `BaseProject`, `ProjectTemplate` and `Project`

```
class ProjectTemplate << BaseProject; end
class Project << BaseProject; end
```

I would like to copy project_template attributes to a new project instance as defaults.

The problem is if i use `dup` project will have `type` set to `ProjectTemplate`

```
project_template = ProjectTemplate.first
project = project_template.dup
```

i can set the type by hand

```
project.type = "Project"
```

but i don't like it that way, or i can do this

```
project_template = ProjectTemplate.first
project = Project.new( project_template.attributes.except("id", "type") )
```

but i read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262546/copy-model-instances-in-rails) which recommends against the second solution.

What whould be the recommended way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's going to be a "better" way that the `dup`, `type=` approach. You could create a class method on Project that you can then use whenever you need to create a project:

```
class Project < BaseProject
  def new_from_template(template)
    project = template.dup
    project.type = 'Project'
    project
  end
end
```

Then you would just need to use this:

```
project = Project.new_from_template(ProjectTemplate.first)
```