# Setting a 'has_many's object to carry it's parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many, belongs-to

I have an object called a `tag` which `has_many :tweets`. The `tweet` also has a corresponding `belongs_to`.

If I'm generating a tweet to save in the `tag` model like so:

```
        new_tweet = Tweet.new

        new_tweet.favorite_count = tweet.favorite_count 
        new_tweet.filter_level = tweet.filter_level 
        new_tweet.retweet_count = tweet.retweet_count 
        new_tweet.text = tweet.text 
        new_tweet.tweeted_at = tweet.created_at 

        new_tweet.created_at = DateTime.strptime tweet.created_at.to_s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z' 

        new_tweet.save
```

How do I set that tweets parent to be the current tag? Would I do something like this?

```
new_tweet.tag = self
```

I tried this and it didn't work, whats a better solution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the `tweet` contains `tag_id` then `new_tweet.tag_id = tweet.tag_id` should work

Comment: @Pavan - You should make this an official answer.

Comment: @miler350 I will wait for OP's confirmation before posting it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create tweet's new object with association and tag_id will automatically assign in your new tweet object. So change `Tweet.new` to `self.tweets.new` and you are done.

```
new_tweet = self.tweets.new

new_tweet.favorite_count = tweet.favorite_count 
new_tweet.filter_level = tweet.filter_level 
new_tweet.retweet_count = tweet.retweet_count 
new_tweet.text = tweet.text 
new_tweet.tweeted_at = tweet.created_at 

new_tweet.created_at = DateTime.strptime tweet.created_at.to_s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z' 

new_tweet.save
```

As per your comment. You also have database structure issue. You need to resolve that first.
You don't have `tag_id` in your `tweets` table assuming you take tag name column. To make my code work properly and create a proper parent child relation you must have parent_id in your child table.

So try add `tag_id` in your `tweets` table and your error will gone. Also your value will save properly.

Comment: So when I add this line that you suggest `new_tweet = self.tweets.new` I get this error: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'tag_id' for Tweet.`. Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: You have database issue here. You need to add tag_id in tweets table. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have two solutions :

1) As suggested by pavan, assign the tag_id of the original tweet to the new tag. This will create the association between `new_tweet` and the tag :

```
new_tweet.tag_id = tweet.tag_id
```

2) Or, if you do create the `new_tweet` in a tag instance method, you can directly create the tweet through the association as suggested by Dipak :

```
new_tweet = self.tweets.build
```

Comment: The first way gives me an error. The second way gives me this error (I originally tried it as `new_tweet.tag = self` but it should be the same as you got on suggestion one, both give me: `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `tag_id``. Way number 2 gives me the same error as I mentioned in a comment below: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'tag_id' for Tweet` so maybe I have a deeper problem here?

Comment: Do you have a "tag_id" column in your database for the `Tweet` model ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better way to do it.

If you're saving a `tag` object, why not just use an `after_create` hook to make another tweet? You're basically copying all the data over anyway...

For example:

```
#app/models/tag.rb
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tweets
    attr_accessor :parent
    #This will allow you to save a tag with attribute "parent" as true. If true, the tweet model will create another tweet. It will need tweaking
end

#app/models/tweet.rb
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :tag
   after_create :new_tweet, if: Proc.new { |tweet| tweet.tag.parent }

   def new_tweet
      new = self.clone
      new.tweeted_at = self.created_at
      new.created_at = DateTime.strptime self.created_at.to_s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z' 
      new.save
   end
end
```

You can read more about [Rails' clone method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262546/copy-model-instances-in-rails) here.

--

**Relational**

Rails is actually very good with handling relational data.

Pavan in the comments is almost spot-on with his recommendation of using `tag_id`. This, of course, will load a database attribute, but there's a better way.

As can be seen [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many), there are a number of methods added with a `has_many/belongs_to` relationship:

[image]

[image]

This means you'll be able to use the following:

- `tweet.tag` to retrieve the tag object.
- If `tweet` had many `tag`, you'd be able to use the `tweet.tag` or
  `tweet.tag_id`

All of this means you can pass an object to your `new_tweet.tag` attribute...

Thus, your answer:

```
new_tweet.tag = tweet.tag
```