# How to copy multiple row with single column update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to copy all the rows from my table with single column update.

Example.

Table County has 1000 rows and i want to copy all the rows with single column update.

What is the proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record) describes how to use `clone` to copy your record.

Assuming the 1000 records are already in an Enumerable called `counties`, we end up with

```
counties.each { |county|  
    county_copy = county.clone
    county_copy.col3 = update_function(county_copy.col3)
    county_copy.save
}
```

Comment: I have already applied this method in my code. But with this code it will create 1000 queries. Can't we insert all this record with single query ?

Comment: Not natively. I'd suggest using the SQL I posted below if this is a one off. And if this is something you need to do on a regular basis, you may need to rethink your data structure. However I did see this blog post which may provide pointers: http://rubypond.com/blog/bulk-insertion-of-data-with-activerecord

Comment: @krunalshah You can build a array of hashes and pass that array to ```Country.create(array) ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, I'd do something like

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, UpdateFunction(Col3)
FROM County
```

Where Col3 is the column you want to update, and UpdateFunction is the function you wish to use to update the column.

EDIT: Of course this is SQL, not Rails - I didn't look close enough at the question's tags :-)

Comment: I want the same thing but with rails way.

Answer (score 0):

@krunalshah You can build a array of hashes and pass that array to

```
Country.create(array)
```

,though it will execute multiple insert queries.

Other option use

```
connection.execute(<<-SQL)
    insert into country1 (col1, col2) 
    select col1, col2 from countries
  SQL
```