# Insert record from object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Does rails have a way to insert records from a model instance?  Something like `User.create(user)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just use `user.save` assuming that `user` is an instance of `User`. AR knows whether to insert or update.

UPDATE (see comments)

This seemed to be a clone of a record issue, so the answer was to use `dup` method to create a shallow clone of the object.

Comment: That's not working as I expected.  For testing purposes, I tried the following:  u = User.find(1); u.id = nil; u.save and it tries to update updated_at where users.id is NULL, which kind of makes sense.  Am I don't something wrong.  I'm selecting this object from User and so it'll always try to update it, when I want to insert it as a new record.

Comment: Why are you setting the id as nil ? You would normally create a new instance using `user = User.new()` and then call `user.save`. By doing a `find` you are selecting an existing record in the database, then setting the id to nil, calling `save` will of course try to save where `id` = nil. Which will blow up. Are you trying to clone a record from the db and save that as a new record?

Comment: should say if you are trying to clone use `dup` that creates a copy of the re4cord without saving it, (Rails 3+)

Comment: Yes.  I want to do a deep clone on a few records, modify them a little, remove a few under some certain condition, and save them as new records.

Comment: yep use `dup` just watch for the deep clone, you may have to check the associations and add them manually.

Comment: Hmm... ok.  If you update your answer w/ the dup, I'll mark this as the answer.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try FactoryGirl to create objects: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl