# using .dup with multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Stripe payment engine for the Catarse project. I have three records I need to copy from my User, who is a project owner to my User's project.  But because I'm a beginner, the code looks like S&%#te!

```
#project_controller.rb

def create
  ...
  check_for_stripe_keys
  ....
end

def show
  ...
  check_for_stripe_keys
  ....
end

....

def check_for_stripe_keys
  if @project.stripe_userid.nil?
    @project.reload
    @project.stripe_access_token = @project.user.stripe_access_token.dup
    @project.stripe_key = @project.user.stripe_key.dup
    @project.stripe_userid = @project.user.stripe_userid.dup
  elsif @project.stripe_userid != @project.user.userid
    @project.stripe_access_token = @project.user.stripe_access_token.dup
    @project.stripe_key = @project.user.stripe_key.dup
    @project.stripe_userid = @project.user.stripe_userid.dup
  end
  @project.save
end

....
```

I only need those three records because my stripe code is an engine. Three things:

1) Initially I thought to user update_attributes but I don't know if its possible to use .dup in that method.

2) Is it possible to put this in a helper located in the engine thats accessible to the main_app so users don't have to edit the main_app project_controller code?

3) Is there a cleaner way to show the above .dup code? 'Cause it's fugly!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more compact way to write what you already have:

```
[:stripe_access_token, :stripe_key, :stripe_userid].each do |field|
  @project.send("#{field.to_s}=", @project.user.send(field).dup)
end
```

Comment: Pretty dang near perfect my friend..and I learned something about ruby arrays. I think lol! ;)

Comment: Its more about that you can methods with send

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

Gemfile:

```
  gem 'deep_cloneable'
```

Code:

```
  @user.dup :include => [:stripe_userid, :stripe_access_token, :stripe_key]
```

I didn't quite follow your relationships.  But take a look at this answer: [What is the easiest way to duplicate an activerecord record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record)

Here is deep_cloneable:
https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable

Comment: Thx..my code above works for me, but I wanted to see if I could do the same in less lines for cleanliness. I'll take a look at deep_cloneable...From looking at it, I don't need to declare where @user.dup is being cloned TO (project) - just need to drop it into my project_controller or model and it will match the records?

Comment: Right, it returns a new record that isn't yet committed to the database.  It does return a record of the same type, so I'm not sure its exactly what you want since it looks like you are trying to copy attributes from the user to the project