# how to return the attributes of a model saved without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a saved model and want to use the attributes of this model to fill a new one.

`b = Model.new model.attributes`

`WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Model: id, created_at, updated_at`

I do not want to give warning to attribute id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `create!` instead of `new`, it will instantiate an object and save it without the callbacks.

```
attrs = Model.last.attributes
new_model = Model.create!(attrs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not duplicate the record? This will give you a new Id but wont keep associations. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record).

```
new_record = old_record.dup
```

GL & HF.

Comment: What does "GL & HF" mean?

Comment: @nickcoxdotme Good Luck and Have Fun. Common in the gaming scene.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the warning use [except](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Except.html) on the attributes hash to get rid of the unwanted attributes:

```
b = Model.new model.attributes.except(:id, :created_at, :updated_at)
```

That should remove those attributes from the hash before passing them into `Model.new`

Answer (score 0):

To copy an ActiveRecord object you should use dup (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup). This will copy your source object except the id and created_at, updated_at type attributes to a new record which you can save when you want to.