# In Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord, how to make an empty ActiveRecord::Relation object and copy a record from another ActiveRecord::Relation object (full)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an ActiveRecord object (x) with some records in it.

First, I want to create an empty recordset (y). Something like :

```
y = x.class.new  EDIT: -or- y = ActiveRecord::Relation.new
```

Second, I want to copy (duplicate) a record from x to y. Something like :

```
y << x.first.dup
```

How can I do that ? (Is it possible ?)

I have an error on the first line, saying that an argument is missing.  I'm able to make new String with this method, but not with ActiveRecord objects.

```
# x.class : ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Analysis
x = Analysis.where(category: 6) 

# In a helper ...
# The x object is not always an Analysis.  So I must use its class 
y = x.class.new
```

Error on the last line :

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)
        from .. /activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:76:in `new'
```

Comment: Answer can be found in answer for the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record

Comment: Is `x` an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object? I.e. is `x` the result of an `ActiveRecord` query like for example `Post.where(...)`?

Comment: @p11y  yes it is.  It's in fact an ActiveRecord::Relation, results of a query to the database.

Comment: Not exactly. I looked at the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record  and all its answers. I didn't find how to create the empty set. I just want to copy few records from the set in an empty one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have an ActiveRecord model `Model`, and a collection of Records `x` that was obtained from a previous query and is of type `ActivRecord::Relation`. Then you can duplicate the entire list this way:

```
y = x.map(&:dup)
```

note that this will set the id attribute to `nil`, you will still have to `create` the records to persist them to the database:

```
y.map(&:save)
```

or in one go:

```
x.each do |record|
  record.dup.save
end
```

If you want to clone just a single record, you don't need the collection wrapped around and you can just do:

```
clone = x.first.dup
clone.save
```