# Duplicating SQL Row in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

A basic function that I just can't get my head around.

I need to copy the values from one MySQL row to a new row - sounds easy.

I've tried the below, setting key_tasks equal to the cloned future_tasks but instead of the expected result of creating new rows for each task, it keeps the same ID, and thus doesn't create a new row. @performance_review relates to the current review taking place and appraisals[-2] relates to the last completed review.

```
    @performance_review.key_tasks = appraisals[-2].performance_review.future_tasks.clone
    @performance_review.save
```

Example row:

```
539 | test1 | 1 | 130 | 2017-04-07 10:27:42 | 2017-04-07 11:02:10
```

Expected after clone:

```
539 | test1 | 1 | 130 | 2017-04-07 10:27:42 | 2017-04-07 11:02:10
540 | test1 | 1 | 131 | 2017-04-07 10:27:42 | 2017-04-07 11:02:10
```

Actual after clone:

```
539 | test1 | 1 | 131 | 2017-04-07 10:27:42 | 2017-04-07 11:02:10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to duplicate an activerecord record?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record)

Comment: Similar, although the ID doesn't change, which is the expected result from my question.

Comment: Hang on, are `key_tasks` and `future_tasks` both `:has_many` relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It seems 'dup' doesn't work on collections.

```
appraisals[-2].performance_review.future_tasks.each do |t|
    t['future'] = 0
    @performance_review.key_tasks << t.dup
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails has an [exclude](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) method for hashes.

So, if you want to clone everything except id, you can use,

```
Foo.find(3).attributes.except("id")
```

e.g.

```
Place.first.attributes.except("id")      
#=> {"name"=>"Seyidin dönəri", "address"=>"Lorem ipsum", "photo"=>"http://press24.az/az/uploads/posts/2013-07/1375267965_1362063196_btn-rk-et-dnr.jpg", "phone"=>"+994502113213", "lat"=>"40.78563", "lng"=>"41.98745", "created_at"=>2017-04-04 07:36:21 UTC, "updated_at"=>2017-04-04 07:36:21 UTC}
```

Then you can pass this hash to `create` method on your model.

e.g.

```
Place.create hash_above
```