# Creating a new object from another object's attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, rails-activerecord

Before introducing `strong params` it was working fine.
So, on creating a new object using `new` and passing attributes, `id` was being set as `nil`.

But now, when I am creating a new object, obj2 from existing object, obj1's attributes,

`id`(a primary key) of obj1 is also being copied to obj2.

Like,

```
obj2 = Post.new obj1.attributes
```

So, problem arises when I try to save it,

```
obj2.save
```

with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error. As both object have the same id.

I have several models with the same use case, so if I use `dup` or `except`, I'll have to add the same in each case.

Comment: Strong params have nothing to do with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to duplicate an activerecord record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a copy of your attributes in a new object, you must use the following (Specific to ActiveRecord) :

```
obj2 = obj1.dup
```

This leaves out `id`, `(created|updated)_(at|on)` from being duplicated. Also remember that the parent associations live as is in the new object.

For more https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `id`:

```
obj2 = Post.new obj1.attributes.except('id')
```

Alternatively, use [`#dup`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup):

```
obj2 = obj1.dup
```

Comment: Thanks. But I did that actually. But I don't want to add `except` everywhere. Isn't this is a property of new method to create a new object?

Comment: @MukarramAli check out `#dup`.