# Rails Console: Create a New Record Using an Existing Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

Recently I had to create a couple of records in a non-rails app database table based on a previous record.  It got me thinking of how would I do this in a rails app.  I tried a couple of things in the Console, but nothing works.

I want to do something like this:

`001> user = User.new(User.first)`

I know this doesn't work but hopefully it will show you what I an thinking.  `User` is a large table/model, and I only need to change a few fields.  So, if I can set up a `new` record with the same values in `User.first`, I can then edit the fields I need to before `.save`-ing the record.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [What is the easiest way to duplicate an activerecord record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
user = User.first.dup
user.assign_attributes(email: "myemail@test.test")
user.save
```

The first line uses `dup` to create a copy of the object. The copy is not yet saved to the database. [Replace `dup` with `clone` if you're using an old version of Rails (<3.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record).

In the second line, `assign_attributes` alters the attributes of the object, still without saving it to the database. If you were working with an object already saved in the database, you could use `update` instead of `assign_attributes` to change the attributes of the object and save the changes in one go. That won't work here, because we haven't saved our duplicate user yet. [More details on that here.](https://davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/)

The third line finally saves the new object to the database. It saves time to just do this once, at the end.

Comment: good answer, though I think your first line should be `user = User.first.dup`

Comment: Thank you, both for the replies.  I never thought of searching on the words `dup` or `duplicating`.   Works great.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Yep, I did mean User.first. Thanks Adam21e. Edited